# Spark FlatMap function for huge lists

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a very basic question. Spark's `flatMap` function allows you the emit 0,1 or more outputs per input. So the (lambda) function you feed to flatMap should return a list.

My question is: what happens if **this list is too large for your memory to handle!?**

I haven't currently implemented this, the question should be resolved before I rewrite my MapReduce software which could easily deal with this by putting `context.write()` anywhere in my algorithm I wanted to. (the output of a single mapper could easily lots of gigabytes.

In case you're interested: a mappers does some sort of a word count, but in fact in generates all possible substrings, together with a wide range of regex expressions matching with the text. (bioinformatics use case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So the (lambda) function you feed to flatMap should return a list.

No, it doesn't have to return list. In practice you can easily use a lazy sequence. It is probably easier to spot when take a look at the Scala `RDD.flatMap` signature:

```
flatMap[U](f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])
```

Since subclasses of `TraversableOnce` include [`SeqView`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.SeqView) or [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) you can use a lazy sequence instead of a `List`. For example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize("foo" :: "bar" :: Nil)
rdd.flatMap {x => (1 to 1000000000).view.map {
    _ => (x, scala.util.Random.nextLong)
}}
```

Since you've mentioned lambda function I assume you're using PySpark. The simplest thing you can do is to return a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead of list:

```
import numpy as np

rdd = sc.parallelize(["foo", "bar"])
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: ((x, np.random.randint(1000)) for _ in xrange(100000000)))
```

Since `RDDs` are lazily evaluated it is even possible to return an infinite sequence from the `flatMap`. Using a little bit of [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz) power:

```
from toolz.itertoolz import iterate
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

rdd.flatMap(lambda x: ((i, x) for i in iterate(inc, 0))).take(1)
```