# How to find a specific record in spark in cluster mode using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a simple csv like this, but its got 1 million records:

```
Name, Age
Waldo, 5
Emily, 7
John, 4
Amy Johns, 2
Kevin, 4
...
```

I want to find someone with the name "Amy Johns". I have a spark cluster of 10 machines. Assuming rdd contains the RDD of the csv, how can I take advantage of the cluster so that I can...

1. Split up the work so that each of the 10 machines are working on 1/10th of the original gigantic set.
2. When the FIRST occurence of "Amy Johns" is found and output to the console, the job is done. (e.g. If Machine #4 found "Amy Johns", all the other machines should stop looking and the result is output)

My code right now just does: `rdd = sc.textFile`

Then it does a `rdd.foreach( // checks if field is "Amy Johns", if so, then exits)`.

The problem I have with this is that the rdd contains ALL the records (if this is not the case, speak up) so I don't think work is being distributed.
Also, I don't know how to finish/stop the job once "Amy Johns" is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RDD by virtue of its definition does contain all of the records. You can split your RDD into multiple partitions to increase the parallelization on computation. Furthermore, after partitioning, you can apply a transformation on your RDD to filter elements according to some criteria.

You may want to try something like this:

```
val myRDD = sc.textFile(_inputPath_, 10)
val filteredRDD = myRDD.filter(line => line.split(",")(0).equals("Amy Johns"))
filteredRDD.first.foreach(println)
```

Comment: So what your showing me above appears to be iterating through all the records. How can I stop after one of the partitioned RDDs finds "Amy Johns", is it possible? (look at #2 of the OP)

Comment: @Rolando I believe calling `first` is what you want to do here. If you look at its implementation, it calls `take(1)` and a good discussion on how `take()` works can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436559/why-apache-spark-take-function-not-parallel). In essence, the `take()`action selects one partition, applies the set transformations in question, and then grabs the number of records desired. If there aren't enough records to grab, `take()` will iteratively select more partitions (at a certain ratio) and again apply the transformations to grab records.

Comment: In your case, once a suitable match is found, the rest of the partitions will not be transformed (lazy computation!).

Comment: Do you know if take "saves" memory compared to collect?  Also, when you do something like take(1), each machine in the cluster is taking (a different one) is that correct? My concern is that this line here: val filteredRDD = myRDD.filter(line => line.split(",")(0).equals("Amy Johns")) is going through all the records even after it gets to "Amy Johns" before you do the .first. If there was a break in that line of some sort (does there eixst one?) then you wouldnt have to iterate through all the records to filter even after you found it.

Comment: Yes, `take()` uses less memory since you are sending a subset of records back to the driver.

Comment: I believe you are getting confused on its implementation. It will start by having only one executor scan one partition to return the number of records desired. If it does not find a suitable record in that partition, it will create more tasks to evaluate further partitions. In our case, `take(1)` will look at one partition to find any record starting with "Amy Johns" and continue from there. This is essentially doing what you desire since it will not filter all partitions immediately, instead waiting until it is necessary to do so.

Comment: Rohan's approach is probably fine if you're only doing one search against `myRDD`. If you're doing multiple searches, however, then it may make sense to do some preprocessing to speed up the searches.Also, if you want the search to happen in parallel in some manner, then you're going to need to split up that computation into multiple rdd transformations/actions.