# How to compare two LabeledPoints in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two `LabeledPoints` - `Prediction1` and `Prediction2`. Both of these `LabeledPoints` have a value as first element and a prediction as second element. I want to check if the `first` element in `Prediction1` is equal to `first` element in `Prediction2` or not. So something like this:

```
for each value in Prediction1 and Prediction2:
     if Prediction1.tup[0] != Prediction2.tup[0]:
         print 'Value unequal'
         break
```

Example:

Suppose following is the `RDD` of `LabeledPoints` `Prediction1`:

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

`Prediction2`:

```
[(1,12),(3,13),(5,2)]
```

In above example 1st element of each `LabeledPoint` of `Prediction1`(1,3,5) is equal to 1st element of each `LabeledPoint` of `Prediction2`(1,3,5). But if even one of these didn't matched then I want to exit of the process and print that they don't match and end.

How can I do that in `PySpark`

Comment: Could provide example input an expected output? Your description is rather vague and this pseudo-code doesn't make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both RDDs have the same number of partitions and elements per partition you can simply `zip` and `take`:

```
prediction1 = sc.parallelize([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)])
prediction2 = sc.parallelize([(1, 12), (3, 13), (5, 2)])
prediction3 = sc.parallelize([(1, 0), (5, 0), (5, 0)])

def mismatch(rdd1, rdd2):
    def mismatch_(xy):
        (x1, _), (y1, _) = xy
        return x1 != y1
    return bool(rdd1.zip(rdd2).filter(mismatch_).take(1))

mismatch(prediction1, prediction2)       
## False
mismatch(prediction1, prediction3)
## True
```

Since `take` is lazy it should work more or less as you expect. See [Lazy foreach on a Spark RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31542779/1560062)

If the initial criteria are not met, you can `zip` manually by combining `zipWithIndex`, swap (`lambda kv: (kv[1], kv[0])`) and `join`.

Comment: So this will end as soon as the 1st mismatch occurs?

Comment: Not necessarily but should be close enough.

Comment: the point is that I have huge data - each rdd has about 20 millions LabeldPoints and I don't want the process to keep running for all those numbers even if the 1st mismatch occurs say at 10th LabeledPoint.

Comment: Long story short this the best thing you can get :)  I may require processing more data than is required but you there is not much you can do about it. If you get an early match it is smart enough to stop without processing all data.