# whether spark loads base RDD in Memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. Need help in understanding how spark works.
Suppose `README.md` is stored in HDFS 128 blocks at 3 nodes and i am using spark shell to process it.

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
val linesWithSpark = textFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark"))
linesWithSpark.first()
```

In above case execution will be triggered by line 3.

Will Spark load complete 3 splits of `README.md`in HDFS node's RAM and then filter the `linesWithSpark` and keep in memory for a moment. And send the first line from `linesWithSpark` (from 1st split)?
Or it will just pull the first line with "Spark" from Split1 of HDFS Node's disk and send it to driver.

What changes to processing if i change the 2nd line to

```
val linesWithSpark = textFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark")).cache()
```

Comment: Not an actual answer but a couple of remarks. You should not care about the precise execution order of steps at the user level, this is what Spark is for. Nevertheless, you can check the execution DAG, in spark's web UI. Another point is that `sc.textFile("README.md")` will look "README.md" file on the path/working directory not on the HDFS, you have to explicitly give HDFS URI to the function/method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with a simple experiment. First lets load data and check its distribution:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md", 2)
textFile.glom.map(_.size).collect
// Array[Int] = Array(54, 41)
```

As we can suspect simple `filter` generates only a single task:

```
textFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark")).toDebugString
// String = 
// (2) MapPartitionsRDD[11] at filter at <console>:30 []
//  |  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at textFile at <console>:27 []
//  |  README.md HadoopRDD[7] at textFile at <console>:27 []
```

Now lets run this job with out `cache` and collect some diagnostic information:

```
val cnt = sc.accumulator(0L, "cnt")

val linesWithSpark = textFile.filter(line => {
  cnt += 1L
  line.contains("Spark")
})

linesWithSpark.first()
// String = # Apache Spark
cnt.value
/// Long = 1
```

As you can see job without cache will process only a single record. It happens because `first` is executed as a `take(1)`. In the first iteration `take` runs the job only [on a one partition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/81da3bee669aaeb79ec68baaf7c99bff6e5d14fe/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1227) and uses `it.take(left)`, where `left` is equal one, on its iterator.

Since `Iterators` are lazy our program returns immediately after processing the first line. If the first partition doesn't provide required results `take` iterates increasing number the processed partition with each iteration.

Next lets repeat the same experiment with with cache:

```
val cacheCntCache = sc.accumulator(0L, "cacheCnt")

val linesWithSparkCached = textFile.filter(line => {
  cacheCntCache  += 1L
  line.contains("Spark")
}).cache()

linesWithSparkCached.first()
// String = # Apache Spark
cacheCntCache.value
// Long = 54
```

Moreover lets check the storage info:

```
sc.getRDDStorageInfo
// Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = Array(
//   RDD "MapPartitionsRDD" (12)
//   StorageLevel: StorageLevel(false, true, false, true, 1); 
//   CachedPartitions: 1; TotalPartitions: 2; MemorySize: 1768.0 B; 
//   ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B)
```

As you can see in case cache Spark will finish to process the partition and cache it in memory. While I cannot provide exact part of the source which is responsible for this behavior it looks like a reasonable optimization. Since partition is already loaded there is no reason to stop the job.

See also: [Lazy foreach on a Spark RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31542779/1560062)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.